# CodeIgniter's URI and form action

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

let's say we are on

```
somesite.com/mail
```

it means we are using controller named 'mail'. This controller has function:

```
public function index(){ 
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('mail/contact_form');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
```

This function is loaded when we type in adress bar just

```
somesite.com/mail
```

and press enter (no additional arguments). And let's see first line of the contact_form view:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="sendmail">
```

And that's my problem. When I type adress with backslash on the end like this:

```
mysite.com/mail/
```

and use my contact formula, everything works good and my Mail controller loads function sendmail and the URL is now:

```
mysite.com/mail/sendmail/
```

But when I forget about backslash (mysite.com/mail), it looks for controller named "sendmail" but I don't want it. My url is then:

```
mysite.com/sendmail
```

but of course I don't have any controllers named sendmail. My question is - how to change action of my formula or what should I do to make this working good? Is the only answer to remember about backslash or what?

Comment: please use `base_url('mail/sendmail')` as your 'action', always use base_url(); to generate links, forms, javascript paths, css/img paths.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As simple example as to give you is to use CI's `site_url()`

`site_url("controller/function")` and it will take care of other url things

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('mail/sendmail');?>">
```

Go through [**url_helper**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, of course now it doesn't matter what url will be, because always the proper function will be loaded. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

please use `base_url('mail/sendmail')`

as follows

`<form role="form" method="post" action="<?=base_url('mail/sendmail')?>">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include(conexao.php)


if($_post) {
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = md5 ($post['senha'];
$sql = 'select * from usuarios where usuario = ' .$usuario. " and senha = " .$senha."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if  ($num_rows >=1_ { 
session_start();
$_session['logado'] = true;
$_session['usuario'] = $usuario;
header('Location: logado.php');
else 
$erro= 1
}
}
?>

<html> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
</head>
<body>

    <section>
        <div class="col-md-8 defaultbox-container">
            <h1>Acesso</h1>
            <?php if($erro){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
              <strong>Erro!</strong> Usuario ou senha incorretos.
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <form role="form" method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Usuario:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Senha:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" >Acessar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include('conexao.php');
    session_start();
    //VERIFICA SE O USUARIO ESTA LOGADO
    if($_SESSION['logado'] == 0){
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8 defaultbox-container">
            <h1>BEM VINDO <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'];?> <small>Painel de controle</small> <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Logout</a></h1>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a code only answer and as such not appreciated, because it lacks explanation and thereby spreads the misconception that StackOverflow is where you coding solutions for things you need It is instead meant to answer questions about programming problems encountered when trying to program something. It also seems to be copied from somewhere without spending the effort to adapt to this English-only community.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change to make in lower case or it wont allow you to submit special characters like ó

```
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
```

Answer (score -1):

First call url helper.
 Then give action in form like `action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/mail/sendmail"`

then write the code in controller function