# update details ci

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am currently trying to allow a user when logged in to update their own details. So far, the user is only allowed to edit user 1 but the form does not populate either. I would like to be able to allow the specific session user to change their details, but don't know what way to go about this. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Login Controller- Login.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('login_model');
    }


    public function index()
    {
         if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
    {
            $this->welcome();
    }
    else    {
         $data['title']= 'MVC Application';
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/nav');
            $this->load->view('login/signin', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
    }


    public function welcome()
    {

        $data['title']= 'MVC Application';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/nav');
        $this->load->view('login/welcome', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }


     public function login()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('pass');

$this->load->library('form_validation');
// field name, error message, validation rules
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Your Email', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Password', 'trim|required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$this->index();
}
else{
 $this->login_model->login($email,$password);
    $this->welcome(); 
} 
}

public function logout()
{
$newdata = array(
'id'   =>'',
'username'  =>'',
'email'     => '',
'logged_in' => FALSE,
 );
$this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );
session_destroy();
redirect('login/index');
}

function update() 
{   $data['title']= 'MVC Application';
     $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/nav');
        $this->load->view('login/update', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    $data = array (
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password') 
    );
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $this->login_model->update($data);
}
}
?>
```

Login model- Login_model.php

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login($email, $password)
    {
    $this->db->where("email",$email);
    $this->db->where("password",$password);
    $query=$this->db->get("mvc_user");

     if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $rows)
    {
  //add all data to session
  $newdata = array(
  'id'  => $rows->id,
  'username'  => $rows->username,
  'email'    => $rows->email,
  'password' => $rows->password,
  'logged_in'  => TRUE,
  );
  }
  $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
  return true;
  }
  return false;
  }

  function update($data) 
 {
 $this->db->where('id', 1);
 $this->db->update('mvc_user', $data);              
 }
 }
?>
```

Update view (located in login folder) update.php

```
<div class="six columns">
<?php echo form_open('login/update'); ?>

<p>
<label for="user_name">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="user_email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="user_password">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="user_password" id="user_password" />
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of update.php?

Comment: Update.php is the last piece of code displayed (form) @RajuDawadi

Comment: You should have the form action to controller. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18706415/2055751)

Comment: Sorry I actually uploaded an older question instead of a newer one... Its updated now. I have managed to allow the user to update user 1, I just need guidance on how I could do this with a specific session user... @RajuDawadi

Comment: You mean user session with id 1 can update the data of user 1, right?

Comment: Yes, at the moment all users can only update user 1. I would like each user to be able to edit their own details @RajuDawadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass the data from the Login controller to the view so that you can pre-populate the form fields:

```
function update() {

    // Prepare data to pass to the view
    $data = array (
        'title' => 'MVC Application',
        'username' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
        'email' => $this->session->userdata('email'),
        'password' => $this->session->userdata('password') 
    );

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/nav');
    $this->load->view('login/update', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    $data = array (
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password') 
    );
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $this->login_model->update($data);
}
```

The view can then access the array elements as individual variables and pre-populate the input fields:

```
<div class="six columns">
<?php echo form_open('login/update'); ?>
<p>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

To save the user's new data in Login_model.php, just get the id from the session:

```
function update($data) {
    $my_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    if($my_id !== false) { // Just making sure we're logged in
        $this->db->where('id', $my_id);
        $this->db->update('mvc_user', $data);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! :) @PetkoBossakov. I have another question... Do you know how I could get the form (when submitted) to redirect to the update page?

Comment: Well in this case you can't redirect because you've already started outputting data. You can do something slightly different, like in this example: http://pastebin.com/VQrPhnDq

Comment: Thank you! I've added your code and everything works great thanks! One small issue... when the form is redirected back, the old information still displays. It only displays the new information if I log out and login again! Any ideas why? @PetkoBossakov

Comment: Looks like the `update` function updates the database, but does not change the session cookie. Try adding `$this->session->set_userdata($data);` in `Login_model::update()`.

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you :) @PetkoBossakov